# PHPExcel generating totally jacked up output

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Greetings,

I am having trouble figuring out how to properly use PHP in general and PHPExcel in particular. I have read multiple posts on this topic and yet I've been running around in circles. Here is the relevant portion of my jacked up code:

```
$viewinv = mysql_connect($sqlsrv,$username,$password);
if (!$viewinv) { die('Could not connect to SQL server. Contact administrator.'); }
mysql_select_db($database, $viewinv) or die('Could not connect to database. Contact administrator.');
$query = "select unit_id,config,location from inventory;";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('blah');

$rowNumber = 1;
$headings = array('Unit ID','Config','Location');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(array($headings),NULL,'A'.$rowNumber);
$rowNumber++;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $col = 'A';
   foreach($row as $cell) {
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
      $col++;
   }
   $rowNumber++;
}
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myFile.xls"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   exit();
}
echo 'a problem has occurred... no data retrieved from the database';
```

PHPExcel is definitely outputting data from the query, I can see bits and pieces of plaintext, but it is surrounded by a ton of random characters as if though I am looking at the contents of a compressed or compiled piece of data.

For example:

```
PKâh¿>G’D²Xð[Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷œ"ò%nY „švAa •(0ö¤±êØ–gúw{&i‰@ÕnbEö{ßøyìÑdÛ¸l mð¥‘×ÁX¿(ÅÛü)¿’òF¹à¡;@1_æ»˜±Øc)j¢x/%ê…Eˆày¦
```

Any pointers would be extremely appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem will likely be resolved by matching the correct writer types to the correct content-types and file extension.

XLSX (office 2007+):

```
Writer      : Excel2007 (PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007)
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

XLS (before office 2007):

```
Writer      : Excel5 (PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5)
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Comment: Initially it was set to Excel5, I set it to Excel2007 to test if it would output correctly. The result is the same in both Excel5 and Excel2007, all data is garbled. Also Excel pops up a warning stating "The file you are trying to open __, is in a different format than specified b y the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"

Comment: Do you get the file extension warning for Excel5 as well or just with Excel2007? Also, what version of Excel (office) are you testing this with?

Comment: With Excel5 and .xls I get that warning. With Excel2007 and .xlsx I get a different warning. "Cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file'. I am using Office Professional Plus 2010.

Comment: Let's try the following: Excel2007, Content Type of 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'.

Comment: Tried, same error. Oddly enough in Internet Explorer it output the same garbled characters directly into the browser rather than attempting to open it as a file in Excel.

Comment: Hey thanks for all of your help -- It finally dawned on me that at the top of the script I had included a header which included the variables for the mysql connection, etc. That header had a ton of CSS stylesheet information in it as well-- after removing the php include and putting the variables directly in this php script the problem has been resolved. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 14):

Your problem is certainly in outputting more content than just Excel data (which is contained in output buffer).

To solve your problem, just call

```
  ob_clean(); //this will clean the output buffer
```

before sending header.

Comment: This is the issue - to test if you're having this issue, write the file to local disk and download manually. If it opens fine in Excel, then the problem is more content as MOleYArd suggests.  In my experience, its not necessary to use the openxmlformats header above, a simple octet content type header will work fine and is more generic and therefore probably more cross-browser/platform friendly.

Comment: Solved my problem ! Thank you !

Comment: Thank you! You saved a day.